# php find string

Tags: php, string, string-search

how to find if this string :

```
132,139,150,166,176
```

is in this one? :

```
132,139,150,166,176,131,140,151,165,175
```

Comment: To raise the chance people will help you, it's advised to accept some answers of your previous questions first.

Comment: Just wondering, why would this specific pair of strings be any more special than any two random strings of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
strrpos("132,139,150,166,176,131,140,151,165,175","132,139,150,166,176");
```

If a string exists, its starting point will be returned from zero onward, if it is not present the result will be 'false'

Comment: The OP seems to be new to PHP.  You should clarify that he should use an identity operator over an equality operator when using `strrpos`, to avoid pitfalls.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to find the occurrence of one string within another.

```
$str1 = '132,139,150,166,176,131,140,151,165,175';
$str2 = '132,139,150,166,176';

if( strpos($str1,$str2) !== false) {
   // $str2 exists within $str1.
}
```

Note that `strpos` will return `0` if `$str2` is found at the beginning of `$str1` which in fact is the case above and will return `false` if not found anywhere.

You must use the identity operator `!==` which checks both value and type to compare the return value with `false` because:

```
0 !== false is true
```

where as

```
0 != false is false
```